# Running tcpdump inside a Docker container as non-root user

Tags: linux, docker, tcpdump

I want to build a Docker image containing tcpdump. That Docker image runs an application that needs to call tcpdump, but it should not run as `root` all the time, for obvious security reasons. Instead, the non-root user should be able to run tcpdump directly.

Assuming the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y \
  libcap2 \
  libcap2-bin \
  tcpdump \
  && apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 user
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 user --shell /bin/bash

RUN groupadd pcap && usermod -a -G pcap user \
  && chgrp pcap /usr/bin/tcpdump \
  && chmod 750 /usr/bin/tcpdump \
  && setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/tcpdump

USER user

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tcpdump"]
```

When I run the image:

```
docker build -t tcpdump:latest .
docker run --rm -it tcpdump
```

… it fails with:

> exec /usr/bin/tcpdump: operation not permitted

Someone else has raised this issue [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2739) but without a response.

What can I do to make this work?

---

Note that in regular installations it is not recommended to modify the permissions and group ownership of `/usr/bin/tcpdump`, as that could be overwritten by system package upgrades. However, since the container image is immutable, this does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Docker container itself is missing the [required capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities) to run `tcpdump`.

You can add those capabilities by adding the `--privileged` option to the `docker run` command, or, even better, only add the capabilities strictly needed:

```
$ docker run --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_RAW  -it tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
^C12:47:29.433403 IP6 :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 1 group record(s), length 28

1 packet captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```